# SDL2 surface and texture have incorrect pixel format

Tags: sdl-2, pixelformat

SDL2 2.0.8. Windows 10. msys64.  Radeon Card.

I'm converting a DirectX (draw) application to SDL2.

In the code, I open both a DirectX window and an SDL window and then verify the pixel format of both.

So on the same machine in the same program DirectX returns an ARGB8888 window but SDL2 returns an RGB888 window. SO 32 bit vs 24 bit???

Is this correct?  How do I get SDL to return an ARGB8888 formatted window?

Comment: Alpha only makes sense if your window is semi-transparent, which isn't directly supported by SDL (and, I suppose, also requires a lot of special tricks with directx). What's your use case?

Comment: While having 32bits per pixel may be nicer for addressing/alignment, I really don't think extra 25% memory pressure will make it faster than 24bits, especially if rendering is performed by GPU.

Comment: @keltar in Lazy Foo tutorial it says that we need to convert loaded images to the screen format to make it quick to render. Converting images with alpha channel loses this channel when converted to RGB888. How about this use case? (tutorial link: http://www.lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/05_optimized_surface_loading_and_soft_stretching/index.php)

Comment: @DmitryMatveyev https://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no problem. You can check the rendering process works or not.